Throw out of main i.e. not caught exception results in SIGSEGV
Given the code
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Test {
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Test obj1;

    try 
    {
        Test obj2;
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception thrown"); 
    } // Object 2 is destroyed here
    catch (...)
    {
        throw; // std::abort
    }
} // not reached (implementation defined), Object 1 destructor never called


I understand why the destructor of obj2 is not called, as it's implementation defined if stack unwinding happens in case of an uncaught exception, but I do not understand why on the usual Linux platforms it's allowed or thinks it has to terminate with a SIGSEGV signal. To my understanding a SIGABRT would be expected.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Isn't that in violation to the Cpp Standard?

[except.handle] "If no matching handler is found, the function std::terminate() is called;" From your godbolt it seems that std::terminate was indeed called. Standard doesn't seem to specify what should happen next, so I guess being killed by SIGSEGV is valid. You can get the same behavior by just calling terminate.

You can get same behavior if your program simply calls std::abort(). C++ standard says std::abort "Causes abnormal program termination" but does not specify it must be SIGABRT signal. abort() is covered by POSIX, which says it should raise SIGABRT signal. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abort.html

There is at least a header  defining the signals and cppref.com is a bit unclear if only POSIX or cpp lang in general mandates std::abort to use SIGABRT
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/SIG_types

This is an artefact(/bug?) of Compiler Explorer. SIGABRT becomes a SIGSEGV: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/5224
Running it on my computer gives:
$ ./example ; echo "Program returned: $?"
Constructor called
Constructor called
Destructor called
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Exception thrown
Aborted
Program returned: 134

Even on Compiler Explorer, you can handle the SIGABRT to see that it is still there, there's just a SIGSEGV after it: https://godbolt.org/z/6dYsP5K5K
std::signal(SIGABRT, [](int) {
    std::cout << "Caught SIGABRT\n" << std::flush;
});
std::signal(SIGSEGV, [](int) {
    std::cout << "Caught SIGSEGV\n" << std::flush;
    std::_Exit(1);
});

Compiler explorer output:
Program returned: 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Exception thrown
Constructor called
Constructor called
Destructor called
Caught SIGABRT
Caught SIGSEGV

My computer:
$ ./example ; echo "Program returned: $?"
Constructor called
Constructor called
Destructor called
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Exception thrown
Caught SIGABRT
Aborted
Program returned: 134


That's what I get for this one time, not executing it on-my-machine™ first :-)
